# It is possible to download signatures in IMAP?

Tags: java, email, smtp, imap

Situation:

I need to make an imap client (using java mail api) that if, for example when synchronising with gmail would also download my signature.

So that next time i send a mail using SMTP, it would automatically include my gmail signature alongside with it.

Is that possible ?

Does IMAP support this or do i need to use another protocol ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature is part of the mail client - it adds it automatically to the sent mails. The actual transport (SMTP/POP3/IMAP) knows nothing on the signature.

You can parse the mails and search for the signature part in order to save it locally.

Comment: Thats fine, being a local client i can configure it to use a predefined signature, but my requirement is global, user can sit remotely (in different clients) and still use the same signature,


Isnt it possible for the client to get the signature from the mail server ?

or should a client keep a seperate repository of signatures per user in a database ?

Comment: IMAP does not support this. The options I see you have is either have a central signature repository (as you suggest) or write a web client.